# reference error - can't find variable d3 - when i try to create a piano using javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a piano based on a particular requirement and I am referring to "https://codepen.io/moffboffjoe/pen/EjEYKg"

When i try to run the same on my local, i get an error - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3
I tried including the corresponding js - I included

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
```

the error occurs in this line -

```
 var svg = d3.get(".svg-container")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width",width)
      .attr("height",height);
```

I don't know which one or both of these are actually needed. But nothing helps so far.

Comment: post all your code or at least some significant part

Comment: check your network tab does the https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js javascript get loaded?

Comment: What broswer are you using?  If you look in your browser dev tools, Net tab, is d3 actually loading?  Is your own script in its own file?  Is that loading?  I tried it myself and it worked fine.  Are you including d3.min.js before your own script?

Comment: thanks @PaulLeBeau - i got it fixed, by including d3.min.js before my own javascript file. I failed to notice that. Anyways, thanks to all :)

Comment: by the way, i think you're mixing d3 version3 (from `cloudfare.com`) and version4 (from `d3js.org`) here which you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `d3.select()` instead of `d3.get()`.
`d3` object is working fine when I use your url.